# Paypal subscription smaller interval

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I would like to create a recurring payment profile with minute interval instead of day/month interval for testing purposes. I have not found anything in the paypal docs about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What part of the application are you testing?

If you're using Payments Standard:

Its probably worth breaking down the testing into various parts.
Payment / PDT can be tested by paying (and then cancelling/refunding the transaction)
I think the IPN can be tested through the simulator, so you can just set that up to test your app.

Comment: I am trying to test subscriptions , but don't want to wait a whole day to test payments or payment failures.